# Physics required to make a basic weighing scale?

Tags: flash, math, physics

Okay so I need to make a basic activity (working Flash/as3) that simulates very basic weighing scales. All the objects that go on to the scales are the same weight.

If you imagine the classic weighing scales (http://www.metalminnie.co.uk/mm1/scales-S1055936773790.JPG) - we are dragging/dropping stuff on to the sides and animating accordingly.

I don't want anything fancy, just the maths required to affect the scales according to how many objects are on each side.

What I'm looking for is probably the angle of rotation of the horizontal arm. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the basic case these sorts of scales with an equal arm on both side will drop one side if it is heavier and remain stationary when they are the same.

With no friction on any parts it will be capable of remaining in any position that it is put in since the moment around the pivot is the sum of (Force x perpendicular distance to pivot) for all forces in question. Here we have two forces in practice. Due to the fact that both arms are an equal length and both masses will apply a force in a parallel direction the perpendicular distance from the line of force to the pivot is the same, no matter the angle of the pivot (until such time as one weight hits the ground at which point the ground starts supporting the weight and it effectively remains stationary.

If you want to create a dynamic system and work out how quickly the scales will drop then you have to start looking at the acceleration of the objects. I'm not 100% sure how to correctly model teh relevant forces to get out your acceleration equation. My first thought was that the forces on each mass were its own mass - the other mass. You can then use each mass and this force to work out acceleration. However, this is not right since this would give different accelerations for each mass which is clearly wrong. The rigidity of the pivot is clearly providing some additional force to keep the two accelerations equal but I'm stumped on how to work out out exactly...

Edit to add additional note:

I was thinking last night and the scenario that somebody else mentioned with the pivot not on the bar connecting them will actually make it lower on one side and not necessarily hit the floor. The reason is that in this situation (imagine an equilateral  triangle with the top point as the pivot and the lower two points as where our weights connect) the pivoting will actually bring one weight closer (the heavier one) and one weight further away (the lighter one) which will restore the balance due to the moments balancing. This is probably a better model to use in many ways to look cool but much harder. :)

If this is of interest then I can try to work out the maths...

Comment: Yeah I just spoke to our resident physics dude and he said the same as you, it'll just drop on one side if there's a greater weight on that side - I was under the impression the amount it would drop would be affected by the ratio of weight to the other side. Apparantly not so the 'model' becomes a trivial if statement, I don't need any actual physics.

Comment: fwiw, it may be useful to leave this question open so someone can post the actual physics, even if I don't need it.

Comment: I'm more than happy for you to unaccept my answer so that it can remain open for others to put thoughts in. Also I added a note with a situation where it would drop by a certain amount (I think) but not necessarily bottom out immediately. I've not done the maths for that one though so I'm not 100% sure how easy it is...

Comment: In fact aepryus seems to have done a solution with the pivot not on the balance bar which might be cool.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I have been unable to calculate (or find) an analytic solution to the above equation, but solving for theta in the above equation will give you the equilibrium position of the balance given the two masses and the angle phi, which is determined by the geometry of the balance.

In order for a pan balance to work, the axis of rotation must be offset from the bar connecting the two pans.  If the axis were not offset, than there would only be equilibirum when m1 = m2 for all angles; or if not equal than when the bar is vertical.

Not sure if you want to animate the occilations as the bar moves towards equilibrium or just move the bar directly towards equilibrium, but barring an analytic solution, a numerical solution will do the trick.  This of course complicates things a bit.

I'll post back if I can find an analytic solution...

Ok, thanks to Chris, the final solution is:

theta = arctan[tan(phi)*(m1+m2)/(m1-m2)]

For what, its worth, here is what it looks like for phi = pi/8 in terms of delta = m2/m1.

[image]

At delta = 0, theta = phi; delta = 1, theta = pi/2; delta = infinity, theta -> pi - phi

Comment: Uggh... the sign of phi in the equation on the diagram above is reversed.  Should be m1 sin(q-j) = m2 sin(q+j). (where q is theta and j is phi)

Comment: This is the kind of thing I was thinking of. I'll have a look at the maths when I get a moment and see if I can find a way to simplify

Comment: I think if you use the identity `sin(A+B) = sinAcosB + SinBCosA` and the fact that `cos(A)=cos(-A)` and `sin(A) = -sin(-A)` and then divide throughout by cos(theta) then you should get an equation for tan(theta) in terms of m1, m2 and phi.

Comment: So, embarassing... My math is seriously out of practice these days.  I was missing the (seemingly obvious now) divide by cos(theta) step.  Thanks for the help; posting analytic solution shortly...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Maybe

```
F1 * b1 * sinα = F2 * b2 * sinβ
m1 * g * b1 * sinα = m2 * g * b2 * sinβ
m1 * sinα = m2 * sinβ
m1 / m2 = sinα / sinβ
m1 / m2 = sinα / cos(90-α)
```

β should be in the other side of F2

I can't go any further because I don't know enough math, but this should be a good launch point.. ;)

PS: This works only for b1 = b2

Comment: Cool, thanks. I have no idea what any of that means but I shall attempt to make sense of it now..

Comment: I think I should add that I know nothing of physics or maths. I spent most of my time in these classes in school drawing robots and looking at girls.

Comment: Me too.. ;) Well, basically since the bar isn't moving the two moments are equal.

Comment: the angles α and β will be the same in this since both of the weights will hang straight down so they are two parallel lines meeting with a straight line so equal angles. Given this all the trig terms disappear immediately and the equations become trivial unfortunately (given b1=b2 they basically say F1=F2 which is the obvious equilibrium position).

Comment: This answer is problematic.  If the axis is colinear with points that attach the chains of the pans, the system will only be in equilibirum if F1 = F2.  For this reason the axis of rotation must be to the side of the line connecting the chains of the two pans.  Look at the picture you provided, you'll noticed the axis is a little above the bar connecting the pans.  The math is a little sticky, but I'll try to post a solution shortly.

Comment: @BlackBear: in that case α + β = 180deg and this means that sin(α) = Sin(β) so the point still stands.